# %(pattern-pair(s)) in ksh93?

Tags: nested, pattern-matching, character, substring, ksh

I've been learning ksh for quite some time but I still cannot understand `%(pattern-pair(s))` in the manual. Anyone can give a simple meaningful example?

```
A pattern of the form %(pattern-pair(s)) is a sub-pattern that  can  be
used to match nested character expressions.  Each pattern-pair is a two
character sequence which cannot contain & or |.  The first pattern-pair
specifies  the starting and ending characters for the match.  Each sub-
sequent pattern-pair represents the beginning and ending characters  of
a  nested  group  that  will be skipped over when counting starting and
ending character matches.  The behavior is unspecified when  the  first
character of a pattern-pair is alpha-numeric except for the following:
       D      Causes  the  ending character to terminate the search for
              this pattern without finding a match.
       E      Causes the ending  character  to  be  interpreted  as  an
              escape character.
       L      Causes  the ending character to be interpreted as a quote
              character causing all characters to be ignored when look-
              ing for a match.
       Q      Causes  the ending character to be interpreted as a quote
              character causing all characters other  than  any  escape
              character to be ignored when looking for a match.
```

Comment: Haha, I've been mildly curious about this for years and have never found _anybody_ that knows about it. There isn't a single example or mention about this anywhere. We've deduced it's something to do with parsing things like nested quotes or parens.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's useful for JSON parsing:

```
json='{"foo":{"bar":"baz"} }'

#remove all quoted values nested in punctuation except the first
jsonroot=${json%%[[:punct:]][[:punct:]]%(\"\")*}

#remove initial curly
jsonroot=${jsonroot#?}
```